# Changing the "standard template" name of the single.php post template

Tags: wordpress, templates, naming

I have a Wordpress website, now i want to change the post template name how it displays in the Wordpress CMS. Now it's saying "Standard template", i want to rename this to "News", just for usability reasons.

I can't find a way to do this. I know you can create new post templates by creating new files, but it always takes the single.php as standard template. I'm also using a child-theme, so i dont want to delete the single.php file, just rename the text: "Standard template".

Thanks in advance.

I tried creating a new post template file with a custom title. This doesnt solve problem, as the single.php file will still be the standard one (i dont want the user to have to change the template).

Answer (score 0):

You can use another single.php for another post type for example if you have news registered as a post type you could have a single-news.php and that file then would server all the single views of postype = news. But from what i understand you would like to create a template appearing to the user with a different name. For that the best practice is to create a directory inside your child theme and name it page-teplates. Inside this directory you can create as many different templates you want and wordpress will recognize them but adding the following code at the top of each template. For the sake of the example lets say i want to create a contact page template. I will create a contact.php file inside the directory page-templates and have these lines of code inside.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Contact
**/

get_header();
/* My templates Code/Design Here */
get_footer();
```

Comment: But the problem with this is, that it doesnt replace the "Standard template" and i have to switch all the current news-items to the new category. I only want to change the name/title of the single template. As i use a child-theme i don't want to delete the single.php from the main theme.

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities are endless.

1. The code in [this post](https://getflywheel.com/layout/create-custom-single-post-templates-wordpress-how-to/) will generate a dropdown box similar to the one that you see in pages. 
   All it requires is a little editing of your child themes functions.php file .

In most cases, you just need to copy your single.php file to a new file name in your child theme and edit the functions.php file in your child theme.  Name your templates as seen in the code Dimitrios posted.

2. consider using the premium [elementor page builder](https://elementor.com/pro/?source=google&medium=cpc&campaignid=1564665745&adgroupid=58994544213&keyword=page%20builder&matchtype=p&adposition=1t1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA7briBRD7ARIsABhX8aCBmLIkk3altpt_h_lNAt4iJGHrbE3pHbh1UwJiIyoFtGQv28uaxDoaAtTsEALw_wcB) to create custom post templates that you can apply at will.
3. Try a plugin like [Post Custom Templates Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-custom-templates-lite/)

Comment: Maybe endless possibilities. But i would prefer to only change the name/display title of this: "Standard template". Should be simple right?